# use __gte for string date django

Tags: python, django

Date is in string format in database

```
class A(models.Model):
   date = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Yah i know it should be date type.
but now we have many records and we will soon change it to date type.
For current status i want get the objects greater than particular date.
So how can i use  date__gte

example

```
objs = A.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.now())
```

Is there any way to achieve this without converting date to datetime field.

Comment: What is string format of your date? Possibly _lexicographical ordering_ may be exploited to get what you want.

Comment: You'll need to [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) your date, and it should work without problems (the format of the string depends on you).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that works. What you can try is a custom manager. So you can create a manager for your model, add something like `date_gte` and then convert the string to a datetime. Then you can user those operators as usual. That's a quick fix for now, but the best solution is to use a DateTimeField, which you want to do as far as I understood.

Example Manager:

```
from django.db import models

class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def date_gte(self, date=datetime.now()):
        items = []
        for obj in self.all():
            if datetime(obj.date) < date:
                items.append(obj)
        return items
```

Then you could call it like `MyModel.objects.date_gte(date=datetime.now())`.

**Note:** This is an expensive query and you may need to convert the simple list into QuerySet object. I haven't tested it, so this example should only help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without a conversion (either in Django or the database during the query) to a proper `DateTime` type. You're trying to compare a `datetime.datetime` to a `str`. That won't work in normal Python and it won't work here.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of string? if it is formatted to `%Y%m%d`, you can use `.extra()` method to do the query.

```
A.objects.extra(where=['date >= date_of_today'])
```

Comment: using extra is highly discouraged. It leaved a door open for hackers.

Comment: @ÖzerS. There are not user input value. What kind of door do you mean?

Comment: @Gaurav But it is hard code like `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d')`.

Comment: @Guinner I thought the date might be inputted by user. But to be honest, if a hacker knows what he/she is doing, you can also input values although it may not be intended that way. As a general rule of thumb, if you have to use extra, something might not be OK in your code. Django devs themselves discourage people to use the extra function. So as a good practice, you should always try to avoid extra queries. So it may be OK in this case, but you never know that hackers might be able to do, so why risk it?